# Listening for when a DOM element is moved

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I'm trying to do basically the equivalent of this CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: calc(100px * nth-child);
```

Given that that's not valid CSS (getting the value of n for nth-child and multiplying it by another value), I'd have to do this with JavaScript. I can do that once on page load easily. What I'd like to do is listen for when the element is moved or reordered so that it can recalculate its position.

This needs to work whether it is moved within its current parentNode, or into a different parentNode entirely.

Anyone know how to do this? Or, alternatively, is there a way to do this with pure CSS I don't know about?

Comment: `nth-child` of what? There seems like there would be better ways to do what you are trying to do. What kind of layout are you trying to build?

Comment: `nth-child` of the parent element. What I'm actually trying to build is a layout which `transform3d`s some web components in a complex manner based on the order in which they appear in the markup, but I'm simplifying it just to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort of answered my own question. Since I'm already planning to use Web Components, it turns out that `attachedCallback` does exactly what I'm looking for.

Finally, I've figured out a real use case difference between `createdCallback` and `attachedCallback`.

Let's say you have:

```
<div>
   <my-element id="a"></my-element>
   <my-element id="b"></my-element>
</div>
```

And then you run:

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.parentNode.appendChild(a);
```

This will move `#a` to the end, producing this:

```
<div>
   <my-element id="b"></my-element>
   <my-element id="a"></my-element>
</div>
```

The key is, when `appendChild` gets called (and, I assume, `insertBefore`, and all the other functions that move nodes around), `my-element` will fire its `detachedCallback` first, and then `attachedCallback`. So if the code to determine its position is included in the `attachedCallback`:

```
myElementPrototype.attachedCallback = function() {
    var myPosition = [].slice.call(this.parentNode.children).indexOf(this);
}
```

then it will get determined again no matter where the element gets moved. This should be compatible with Virtual DOM APIs like React, et al.

As for how to do this without Web Components, then I guess the answer would be to do whatever [document-register-element](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element/blob/master/src/document-register-element.js) does to polyfill `attachedCallback` and `detachedCallback`. A quick glance looks like it's something with MutationObservers and rather complicated.